# How to build a readonly root filesystem in Arch-ARM

Tags: raspberry-pi, readonly, root-filesystem, flash-memory, arch-arm

I have the following set-up:

- hw: RPi 3 Model B
- os: 4.4.37-1-ARCH #1 SMP armv7l GNU/Linux
- file system: /boot(vfat), /(ext4), /var(ext4)
- partitions: three; mounted: /boot, /, /var
- storage: mlc nand flash micro sd

Recently I am getting kernel panic errors at boot time referring to a file in lib which turns out to be some how corrupted.

`kernel panic "/sbin/init" error while loading shared libraries  /usr/lib/libseccomp.so.2 invalid elf header`

So my theory is that since my root file system is NOT readonly and I am using nand flash and there are unexpected shutdowns, some files are getting corrupted.

The goal is to make the root file system readonly so that it may solve the problem.

Unfortunately I could not find any good solid source on how making a readonly root file system should be done on Arch Linux.

Also posted on Arch Linux Forum: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11621

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, what I ended up doing was to just modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` and replace `rw` with `ro` for root:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro
```

also modify the `fstab` as follow to set `boot` partition as readonly. note that `/var` is **NOT** readonly:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults,ro,errors=remount-ro        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /var    ext4    defaults,noatime        0       2
```